# Outlook app shows notifications but corresponding emails are MIA

Tags: notification-bar, outlook

I've been using the Outlook app on my Android for years. This just started happening a few weeks ago. I often will get emails and see the notifications but when I open the app, they're not there. Sometimes it takes hours until the new emails are visible in the app. So as soon as I dismiss the notification either by swiping it away or by opening the app, I have no hint as to what my new emails are about. At the same time, I know those emails are in my inbox both because I read the notification as well as being able to read them in a browser or Windows app. I've already tried using the app's "reset account" which does nothing to help this. Please advise. Thank you!

*Outlook app version 4.2247.1

Samsung Galaxy S9

Phone model number SM-G960U1

Android version 10

One UI version 2.5*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I went into the phone's app settings and hit "clear **cache**" for Outlook. It only helped for about an hour.

Then, in the same location, I chose "clear **data**" for the app. It *seems* to have solved the problem for now. (Warning: doing so will remove your email account from the app. You'll need to re-add it.) We shall see...